# What are the purposes of "tags" in template strings with ES2015?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I saw that tags can be used like this, and you may need it for "security" reasons, anyway, here is the example I got :

```js
let person = 'Mike';
let age = 28;

function myTag(strings, personExp, ageExp) {

  let str0 = strings[0]; // "that "
  let str1 = strings[1]; // " is a "
  let ageStr;

  if (ageExp > 99) {
    ageStr = 'centenarian';
  } else {
    ageStr = 'youngster';
  }

  return str0 + personExp + str1 + ageStr;
}

let output = myTag `that ${ person } is a ${ age }`;

console.log(output); // that Mike is a youngster
```

But what is the point of "tagging" some strings, you do not even need that to get the result of this example, a simple function can do the job, could you give me an other example and some explanation with it ?

Comment: Have you seen this document? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

Comment: So, your code example is taken directly from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) where it explains what the tag does.  Did you read that?  What did you not understand about that explanation.

Comment: Multiple use cases in the [first Google search result](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-tagged-template-literals-a45c26e54761) I found on the topic.  Others described in other links from the Google search.

Comment: Yes I read it but I could do the same with a function, why using a tagged template to return an escaped string ? I see that the benefit is to simply pass the string we want to rework as the first parameter and in the tag we can get each parts of the string (splitted by ${params}) separately with the string part index like : string[0]. Is that all ?

Comment: @Moff - Think about how you'd do it with a function.  It's not as clean as with the tagged template.   You'd have to pass each and every variable separately that you already specified in the template string, essentially making you double specify each variable.  Then, unless you put those variables in an object to associate them with a variable name, you wouldn't know which parameter to the function was which variable in the template. If you want to do your own template processing, tagged template functions are way, way simpler than an ordinary function call. Try implementing your own function.

Comment: In other words - why ` myTag `that ${ person } is a ${ age }`;` and not `myTag('that ', person, ' is a ', age);`. I guess it makes for easier reading, for one.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes indeed, it is some utility tool I could write and I will spend time for that, it was all i wanted to know. I was thinking I missed something more about security that tagging did, but it is only an use of tagging. Anyway thanks guys, I should de-stress a little bit when I learn a language feature.

Comment: You can use `String.raw`, which can be very useful, and is only possible through the use of a tagged template.

Comment: This question would have been a lot better question is you showed you fully understand what they do, you showed your function replacement that doesn't use tagged templates and you asked for some examples of good uses cases for tagged templates so you could better understand where it would be most useful to use.  Instead, you sort of attack the feature without showing what you already did or didn't understand about it and leave us confused about what exactly to explain here.  As it stands now, it's both "too broad" and a bit "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the community answers here and the documentation :

1. https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-tagged-template-literals-a45c26e54761
2. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

the purposes are that you do not have to pass each and every variable separately:

```
myTag`that ${ person } is a ${ age };`
```

and not

```
myTag('that ', person, ' is a ', age);
```

and inside the tag function "myTag" you can access each part of the string separated by a placeholder like this one ${placecholder} with its index : string[0] // that, string[1] // person, etc.

It is some utility tool that allows you to make easy replacement of placeholders.